# Move zipped files from multiple subfolders into one master folder via loop process

Tags: excel, vba, file, loops, unzip

I am trying to:

First Prompt: Ask the user to select the folder that contains all zipped folders where each zipped folder contains a data file.

Second Prompt: Ask the user to select the master folder path to place the unzipped data files.

The program will unzip the first zipped folder, copy the data file, paste the data file into the designated master folder the user was prompted to select from their second prompt.

The program will find the next zipped folder, unzip and open the folder, copy the file it contains, paste the file into the master folder, repeat until all the files from each of the zipped folders are moved.

I am trying to make a folder that contains all the zipped data files in order to concatenate all the data into a master document. Then I will run an analysis on this data.

This code works on folders that are not zipped. I need the code to recognize zipped folders and the "*.csv" file each zipped folder contains.

```
Option Explicit
Public FolderPath As FileDialog

'This program copies files from multiple folder locations into one folder location.

Sub CopyFiles()

Dim objFSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As Object 'File
Dim objFolder As Object 'Folder
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strNewFolder As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Retrieve target master workbook data folder path from user
Set FolderPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FolderPath
    .Title = "Select a master folder location to store the unzipped files."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo CancelSelect1
    strNewFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In case Cancel selected
CancelSelect1:
strNewFolder = strNewFolder
If strNewFolder = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Retrieve target data folder path from user
Set FolderPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FolderPath
    .Title = "Select folder location that contains the zipped folders with desired data files."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo CancelSelect2
    strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In case Cancel selected
CancelSelect2:
strFolder = strFolder
If strFolder = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder & "\").SubFolders
'If Right(objFolder.Name, 2) = "tb" Then
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'If InStr(1, objFile.Type, "Excel", vbTextCompare) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill strNewFolder & "\" & objFile.Name
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

            Name objFile.Path As strNewFolder & "\" & objFile.Name
        'End If
    Next objFile
'End If
Next objFolder

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
ResetSettings:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"
Application.Cursor = xlDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: You already have one post closed, [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423447/vba-unzipping-files-from-multiple-subfolders-and-pasting-all-data-files-into-one) and you still haven't supplied any information on what is happening, what's not happening and what you need help with.

Comment: This code works on folders that are not zipped.  I need some help with getting the code to recognize zipped folders and the "*.csv" file each zipped folder contains.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to loop through a directory, get all the zip files and copy the items (CSV files) to a new location.  You need to add a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation

```
Sub UnzipFile(savePath As String, originalPath As String)
Dim oApp As Shell
Dim strFile As String
'get a shell object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    'get all the files in the directory that are zip files
    strFile = Dir(originalPath & "*.zip")
    'loop until we cannot find anymore files
    Do While strFile <> ""
            'check to see if the zip contains items
            If oApp.Namespace(originalPath & strFile).Items.Count > 0 Then
                Dim i As Integer
                'loop through all the items in teh zip file
                For i = 0 To oApp.Namespace(originalPath & strFile).Items.Count - 1
                    'check to see if it is a CSV file
                    If UCase(Right(oApp.Namespace(originalPath & strFile).Items.Item(i), 3)) = "CSV" Then
                        'save the files to the new location
                        oApp.Namespace(savePath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(originalPath & strFile).Items.Item(i)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        'get the next file in the directory
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
'free memory
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: My Add-Ins menu is completely empty.  I believe that is where you set up a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.  Ever run into this issue?  Know how to fix it?  I'm looking up information on why this is now.

Comment: I found where I needed to set up the reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.  Program worked great, just had to add in the user request dialog boxes on where to find the zipped folders and where to find the master folder to pasted them to.

Comment: On my test run, I used only 6 zipped files and it ran through the files in about 2 seconds.  Now I've moved 8020 zipped files to my "TestZipped" folder to have these files processed and the program is moving over one file every 8 seconds.  This will take 19 hours to complete.  Is there a way to modify the code to speed this up?